# Julia: creating SparseArrays

Tags: julia, sparse-matrix

I want to create a sparse array where I define a rule to combine duplicates. The documentation says that I can do this with `sparse(i,j,v,[m,n,combine])`. I've tried in the example below but am unsuccessful. Can you please advise?

```
i = [1,2,3,3];
j = [1,2,3,2];
v = [10.,11.,12.,13.];
full(sparse([i;j],[j;i],[v;v], [3,3,combine(a,b)=mean([a,b])]))
full(sparse([i;j],[j;i],[v;v], [3,3,mean]))
full(sparse([i;j],[j;i],[v;v], [3,3,-(a,b)]))
full(sparse([i;j],[j;i],[v;v], [3,3,-]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Square brackets in docstring mean that those are optional arguments. The way to write it is:

```
julia> full(sparse([i;j],[j;i],[v;v], 3,3,-))
3×3 Array{Int64,2}:
 0   0   0
 0   0  13
 0  13   0
```

you can omit the last argument, then combine defaults to `+`:

```
julia> full(sparse([i;j],[j;i],[v;v], 3,3))
3×3 Array{Int64,2}:
 20   0   0
  0  22  13
  0  13  24
```

You can check what argument sets the function accepts using `methods(sparse)`. Additionally if you e.g. write `@edit sparse([i;j],[j;i],[v;v])` you will go to the source code of `sparse` and can learn exactly what is accepted.

Comment: Thanks! How do I do `full(sparse([i;j],[j;i],[v;v], 3, 3, mean))`?

Comment: I do not know a simple method. This is the simplest I can find: ```a = sparse([i;j],[j;i], [v;v]);
b = sparse([i;j],[j;i], 1);
full(a ./ (b + (b .== 0)))```